# tty1 and switch users not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: login, gui, users, tty

I very recently switched to ubuntu, and am having a problem with the switch users and the tty1, I've seen in a post here that tty1 is supposed to be the gui login screen and gui desktop on tty2. However ctrl+alt+f1 gives me a black screen with a cursor and hands, if i switch to tty2 it gives me a tty2 terminal session. i am using gdm3 if that helps.

Comment: What happens on a fresh boot? Do you get a gui login screen?

Comment: What do you have on tty7 ?

Comment: @darth_epoxy yeah i get a gui login screen if i reboot it

Comment: tty should be core functions and I am unsure what could interfere with that. WHat do you get after a fresh boot/login when youj open a terminal and type `ls /usr/bin/*session` please?